# Injecting components on standard Salesforce pages

Tags: visualforce, javascript, ui

This is more of knowledge question. I want to detect all the phone fields on the salesforce standard page and convert them into a hyperlink, on clicking of which some action needs to be performed. I know this is possible but wanted to know how ? I tried searching for it and read many articles about home page components etc. but I was not able to find what I was looking for.
Phone field can be anywhere, in the list view, detail page, contact, account, lead etc. Attaching image below which would make things more clear.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no longer possible to directly modify the UI with any code you can host directly in Salesforce. Any articles you may have seen regarding this are outdated. Anything else you might attempt to do may or may not work in the future and would not be officially supported.

Now, if you want to override a specific page, you can do this:

```
<apex:page standardController="XYZ">
    <apex:detail />
    <script>
    // Your detection/modification script here
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

But you will have to do this for each object detail page you want to override. Replace XYZ with the name of the standard or custom object you want to override. Once the page is created, go to the object's setup page (e.g. Setup > Customize > Accounts or Setup > Create > Objects), and override the "View" action with your Visualforce page.

Comment: What about LEX?

Comment: Okay. Can I do something like put my script in the component which will be displayed in the left sidebar ?

Comment: @y.dixit Nope. That's what I tried to convey. This no longer works.

Comment: @AdrianLarson VF still works in LEX, but you can't affect other components. There's no good solution for LEX at all.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am using coupe of chrome plugins which add different UI components (like Apex class quick search by name etc) onto my salesforce setup page. I wonder how does these plugins work then ? If it is not supported anymore.

Comment: @y.dixit Plugins can modify the page's code after it loads. This is not the same as customizing salesforce to inject code via "sidebar hacks" or such. Each browser needs to independently install the plugin in order to use it. Prior to the discontinuation of code injection techniques, you could write code that would modify the page's behavior without using plugins.

Comment: @sfdcfox okay ... so if I am understanding this correctly then...plugins modify these pages on load using JavaScript right ? also as this plugins are able to provide functionalities like searching all the apex classes and etc. I am assuming that they can talk to the SF org securely of the currently logged in SF user   ... I tried to search for some starter code or some tutorial which will give be head-start in understanding this so that I can come up with my own plugin but I was not able to find one.... do you know any such tutorial ?

Comment: @y.dixit You'll need to look for things like "sfdc chrome" on pages like GitHub or GitLab. I myself have dabbled in extensions, they are pretty straightforward, but you'd need to learn a bit about writing Chrome extensions, which is definitely outside the scope of this site.